# How to identify if a directory is a symlink pointing to a network location in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET, what is the best way to identify if a directory is a symlink pointing to a network location?

To determine if it's a symbolic link OR an [NTFS junction point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) we can use:

```
System.IO.File.GetAttributes(folderName).HasFlags(FileAttributes.ReparsePoint);
```

But that's not precise enough as it returns true for junction points as well.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485155/check-if-a-file-is-real-or-a-symbolic-link there are some answers but nothing has been accepted

Comment: "Check if a file is real or a symbolic link" is related but it's not a duplicate. The difference is file vs folder and I also want to determine if a symlink points to a network resource.