# UnauthorizedAccessException while scanning directory 'User\Documents\My Music'

Tags: c#-4.0, directory

1. **Question:** Why do I get this error while scanning a users 'My Documents' folder, but not when I scan the 'My Music/My Pictures/My Videos' directory?
2. **Secondary,** ***less important question***:  Is there a way to avoid this without having to specifically filter these folders out, or using a try/catch block?

*I prefer answers that teach me how to fish, instead of just giving me fish.  Just at this point I am not sure where I need to look to specifically answer this question.*  I've read through documents about [elevating permissions](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/09/29/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-4-_1320_-User-Account-Control.aspx) and [iterating through the file system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx), and spent a good week looking for why I can set DirectoryInfo on 'User\My Music' but not 'User\Documents\My Music'(link) and just would enjoy a little boost in a different direction in regards to learning more.

I catch the initial 'UnauthorizedAccessException' that is thrown initially when attempting Directory.GetFiles('path', "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) where path is the users 'My Documents'.  To handle the exception I know that I need to walk the directory manually.  Which works, returning the files from the sub-directories.

The code for the initial GetFiles function:

```cs
public static string[] GetFiles(string path)
{
    string[] files;
    try
    {
        files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
    catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    { files = WalkDirectory(path); }
    return files;
}

public static string[] WalkDirectory(string path)
{
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
    {
        try
        {
            files.AddRange(WalkDirectory(subDir.FullName));
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            // complete fail to walk directory listed
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        files.Add(file.FullName);
    }
}
```

This works out perfectly, until the code attempts to walk the hidden folders: My Music, My Pictures, or My Videos.  No matter how I try and re-code to walk the hidden files, I keep receiving the UnauthorizedAccessException.

I understand completely that I am going to code around this.  Mainly what I am curious to know, is why is the exception happening under a users folder?

An asssumption I am making is that the folder is a symlink to another directory, because I can make the path **?:\users directory\user\My (Music, Pictures, or Videos)** and the code walks those directories then without any issues.  This only happens when trying to scan the directory files after setting them from within the users My Documents.

- **OS:** Windows 7
- **User Privliages:** Administrator
- **Application Elevated to** run as administrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was speaking about this with a friend, who is not technical, but knows enough tech to hold a conversation and he helped me narrow this question down further.  This is actually a duplicate question and was answered at [Check if a file is real or a symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485155/check-if-a-file-is-real-or-a-symbolic-link).

The folder is a symbolic link that was placed there for backwards compatibility purposes according to this article on ***TechRepublic: [Answers to some common questions about symbolic links](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/answers-to-some-common-questions-about-symbolic-links/3034)*** under the section **Windows Vista and Windows 7 have built-in symbolic links** paragraph 2.

In order to specifically avoid attempting to scan this directory without a Try/Catch block on an UnauthorizedAccessException the folder attributes need to be checked to determine if the folder or file in question is a symbolic link.  Which again was answered in the above listed stackoverflow question.