# Using Windows cmd to delete all SYMLINK filetypes listed after search?

Tags: windows, cmd, symlink

So this command

```
dir /al /s | findstr "<SYMLINK>"
```

Finds all the SYMLINK file types in a specific folder and subfolders. I want to delete just the symlink file NOT the target it is connected to, but I am having trouble finding a command to do that. None of the file types listed as SYMLINK have the actual symlink extension attached to them.

Comment: Take a look at this Super User thread: [How can I delete a symbolic link?](https://superuser.com/q/167076)

Comment: Note that `/al` includes all reparse points, not just symlinks. You could end up deleting much more than you bargained for if you're not careful to filter "<SYMLINK>" and "<SYMLINKD>". There are many types of reparse points -- including mountpoints, OneDrive files, app execution aliases, and HSM recall-on-access files. Of course, you also have to be careful to remove directory reparse points via `rmdir` instead of `del`. As to a "symlink extension", that doesn't make sense, unless you're confusing filesystem symlinks with shell links (i.e. .lnk files).

Comment: The answers on this question are helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/817794/447901

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('dir /AL /S /b') do (del "%~a")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.